# ¿Cómo ordenar una consulta nativa en SPring Boot por una columna con alias?

Tags: sql, spring, ordenar, boot

Tengo una consulta nativa en Spring Boot, ordena por todas las propiedades de la tabla tp, pero no logra ordenar por la columna rating

Esta es la consulta que realizo, como pueden ver utilizo paginación y las propiedades vienen en la instancia `Pageable`

```
    @Query(value = """
                SELECT tp.uuid, tp.name, tp.resume, tp.image_icon imageIcon, 
                tp.created_at createdAt, ROUND(AVG(tpr.punctuation), 1) rating
                FROM tourist_places tp
                LEFT JOIN tourist_places_rating tpr ON tpr.entity_fK = tp.uuid
                WHERE tp.is_public = TRUE
                AND LOWER(tp.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :filter, '%'))
                GROUP BY tp.uuid
                """,
                countQuery = """
                        SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM tourist_places tp
                        WHERE tp.is_public = TRUE AND
                        LOWER(tp.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :filter, '%'))
                        """,
                nativeQuery = true
        )
        Page<ITouristPlaceItem> filterAllPublicPageable2(
                Pageable pageable,
                @Param("filter") String filter
        );
```

Lanza el siguiente error, al parecer no logra captar las columnas que no tengan nada que ver  con algunas de las tablas

```
    order by tp.rating asc fetch first ? rows only
    2023-05-11T16:03:15.216-04:00  WARN 11940 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
    2023-05-11T16:03:15.216-04:00 ERROR 11940 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column tp.rating does not exist
      Position: 316
    2023-05-11T16:03:15.248-04:00 ERROR 11940 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT tp.uuid, tp.name, tp.resume, tp.image_icon ImageIcon,
    tp.created_at createdAt, ROUND(AVG(tpr.punctuation), 1) rating
    FROM tourist_places tp
    LEFT JOIN tourist_places_rating tpr ON tpr.entity_fK = tp.uuid
    WHERE tp.is_public = TRUE
    AND LOWER(tp.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', ?, '%'))
    GROUP BY tp.uuid
     order by tp.rating asc fetch first ? rows only]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause
```

¿Cómo lo podría solucionar, o que otra aternativa tengo para hacer lo mismo?

NOTA: Ya intente con JPQL y se me complico un poco más, por eso opté por una consulta nativa.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

¡Solucionado!, estaba probando con los argumentos que puede recibir la anotación @Query y me encontré con **queryRewriter**, para el cual hay que implementar una clase con la interface *QueryRewriter*, al sobre escribir el método "rewrite", le decimos que reemplace "tp.rating" que no existe en la consulta, por "rating" que es el alias que se le da en la misma.

```
package com.backpackerapi.backpacker.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryRewriter;

public class TPQueryRewriter implements QueryRewriter {
    @Override
    public String rewrite(String query, Sort sort) {
        return query.replaceAll("tp.rating", "rating");
    }
}
```

esta Clase se la debe agregar en la propiedad **queryRewriter** como argumento de @Query:

```
@Query(value = """
            SELECT tp.uuid, tp.name, tp.resume, tp.image_icon imageIcon, 
            tp.created_at createdAt, ROUND(AVG(tpr.punctuation), 1) rating
            FROM tourist_places tp
            LEFT JOIN tourist_places_rating tpr ON tpr.entity_fK = tp.uuid
            WHERE tp.is_public = TRUE
            AND LOWER(tp.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :filter, '%'))
            GROUP BY tp.uuid
            """,
            countQuery = """
                    SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM tourist_places tp
                    WHERE tp.is_public = TRUE AND
                    LOWER(tp.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :filter, '%'))
                    """,
            nativeQuery = true,
            queryRewriter = TPQueryRewriter.class
    )
    Page<ITouristPlaceItem> filterAllPublicPageable2(
            Pageable pageable,
            @Param("filter") String filter
    );
```